# Updating hidden field value on change of star value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a star ranking system for my website. I have an `input` tag which with the help of javascript becomes a star rating point.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<input id="input-21b" value="3.5" type="number" class="rating" min=0 max=5 step=0.2 data-size="lg" onchange="javascript: something1();">
<br>
<input type="hidden" id="input-21b-val" name="input-21b-val" value="">
```

JavaScript:

```
function something1()
{
    var d = document.getElementById('input-21b').value;
    document.getElementById('input-21b-val').value = d;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is, when someone rates the star, the value is changed of the hidden box. So suppose if `1.6` is chosen (the variable `d` shows the info correctly `onchange()`).

So suppose if the rating is `1.6`, the value should be `1.6`, if it changes to `2.5`, the value in hidden box should be `2.5`.

But the value in the hidden field isn't updated.
(I've also tried `.innerHTML` , it too didn't work.)

What have I done wrong?

URL to my setup :- http://novostack.com/stars/examples/

Comment: Your code works fine in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6ggtfrhm/ Also note that having a hidden field that only mirrors the value of the `number` field is redundant, you can send the `number` value to the server the same as you would any standard `input` element.

Comment: There's no jQuery code in your question, it's just plain Javascript. FYI, you don't need to use `javascript:` at the beginning of `onXXX` attributes. That's only needed when you put Javascript code in an attribute that normally contains a URL.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan
What might be the reason of it not working at my end?
Here's a URL :- http://novostack.com/stars/examples/

Comment: Your code on that link appears to be working fine for me. What makes you think there's a problem? If it's because you are getting no value in your PHP, I would look at that script as the source of the issue, not your JS.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan
Select any rating and then view the the source, this field (<input type="hidden" id="input-21b-val" name="input-21b-val" value="">)
Value of it would always be blank.

Comment: Note that the source is not live updated - you need to use the DOMInspector. I can see from that that the value of the element is being updated fine.

Comment: For me it works fine http://prntscr.com/7o351d